# Undefined index: post_type at woocommerce order page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

while at the woocommerce order page, it show

> Notice: Undefined index: post_type in /.../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php on line 848

this is the code for line 848

```
public function search_custom_fields( $wp ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' !== $pagenow || empty( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) || 'shop_order' !== $wp->query_vars['post_type'] || ! isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) { // WPCS: input var ok.
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: see the thread ady, still not sure where cause the problem..

Comment: Error is not due to the plugin. I think it is due to any customization of theme.

Can you change the theme and check that the error still comes or not.